# Issue when adding multiple objects to state in React using useContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-context

I'm working on an e-commerce application using React, and I'm having trouble adding multiple objects to a state using the `useState` and `useContext` hooks. In my case, I have a state called select, which is an array of objects. My goal is to add multiple selected products to the shopping cart through the context using the `addProductToCart` function provided by the `CartContext`.

However, currently, only the last object of the array is being stored in the shopping cart, instead of all the selected objects. Here's the relevant code:

```
const SetupPage = ({ products }) => {
    const { addProductToCart } = useContext(CartContext);
    const [select, setSelect] = useState([]);

    // falta agregar items del select en el carrito de compras
    const onAddProduct = () => {
        const filteredProducts = select.filter(
            (product) => product.inStock > 0
        );

        filteredProducts.map((product) => {
            let priceWithDiscount =
                product.price - product.price * (product.discount / 100);

            let tempCartProduct = {
                id: product.id,
                description: product.description,
                image: product.images,
                price: product.discount > 0 ? priceWithDiscount : product.price,
                slug: product.slug,
                title: product.title,
                inStock: product.inStock,
                discount: product.discount,
                quantity: 1,
            };

            addProductToCart(tempCartProduct);
        });

    };
    
    return (
        // JSX del componente...
    )
};
```

Function `addProductToCart`:

```
const CART_INITIAL_STATE = {
    isLoaded: false,
    cart: [],
    numberOfItems: 0,
    subTotal: 0,
    tax: 0,
    total: 0,
    shippingAddress: undefined,
};

const addProductToCart = (product) => {
        const productInCart = state.cart.some((p) => p.id === product.id);
        if (!productInCart)
            return dispatch({
                type: "[Cart] - Update products in cart",
                payload: [...state.cart, product],
            });

        // Acumular
        const updatedProducts = state.cart.map((p) => {
            if (p.id !== product.id) return p;

            // Actualizar la cantidad
            p.quantity = product.quantity;
            return p;
        });

        dispatch({
            type: "[Cart] - Update products in cart",
            payload: updatedProducts,
        });
    };
```

I have tried iterating over the filteredProducts array and calling addProductToCart within a ``.map() function to add each product to the shopping cart. However, this only results in storing the last product from the array.

I would appreciate any guidance or solution to correctly add all the selected products to the shopping cart using the context.

Thank you for your help!